# Using linux pipe output as partial input

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Running a `grep` command on my file gives me the following output:

```
15-5-65
52-5-93
51-4-82
21-0-86
54-6-09
63-2-68
26-7-85
24-9-46
16-7-59
81-5-42
31-7-63
54-0-84
69-8-80
74-1-27
19-9-86
41-8-74
13-2-03
21-3-61
56-7-60
81-9-47
```

I want to use each of these as a partial input to another `grep` command, such as `grep '02729-AS-27' maps/projects.dat | grep '...-...' circuit_(pipe input).dat` How do I properly format this command?

If this isn't clear, the files I want to search are called for example `circuit_81-5-42.dat` with numbers corresponding to the output of the first `grep` command above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep "...-..." "circuit_${line}.dat"
done < <(grep "02729-AS-27" "maps/projects.dat")
```

Or:

```
grep "02729-AS-27" "maps/projects.dat" | xargs -i grep "...-..." "circuit_""{}"".dat"
```

Please replace the pattern `...-...` with the appropriate one.

Hope this helps.